Problemas para capturar los **formControlName** de un formulario dinámico generado a traves de un **JSON**
Estoy intentando capturar los datos de un formulario dinámico utilizando formularios reactivos de Angular, pero como los formControlName son dinámicos, no los puedo configurar en el FormBuilder del componente.
Como podría configurar los formControlName en el archivo ts del componente, para poderlos luego almacenar en la base de datos?.
<div class="row">
      <!-- Three Folders -->
      <div *ngIf="showForm" formArrayName="items">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <div class="card border-dark mt-2 mb-4" *ngFor="let val of modelsaved">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ val.fld_name }}
              <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let iter of val.formfield; let i = index">
                <label>{{ iter.label }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="{{ iter.type }}" name="{{ iter.label }}"
                  [formControlName]="i">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" (click)="saveTemplate()"><i
                class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i>
              Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- More 3 fields -->
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
        <div *ngIf="!showForm" formArrayName="items">
          <div class="card border-dark mt-2 mb-4">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ objInfo.adm }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let item of modelsaved; let i = index">
              <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="{{ item.type }}" name="{{ item.label }}"
              [formControlName]="i">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" (click)="saveTemplate()"><i
                class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i>
              Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

Este es mi formulario

Agrega el código del componente.
